# Hack Firefox to use custom URLs?

Tags: url, firefox

I am using an extension that depends on the page. I would like to use the extension for each board which means I need a board unique url. It currently looks like this

```
http://phpbb-site.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=BOARDNUMBER
```

I'd like to trick Firefox into having BOARDNUMBER in the location part of the url.

Then the extension will work and I won't have to tweak it. The problem is that I can't think of any way I can have Firefox use nice urls. I only need it to work on my computer.  I don't own the site. What can I do? Can I use a proxy program? I was thinking maybe I could write a quick asp.net program which essentially does a GET request on the site and replaces all links to include the boardnumber and ignores that part of the url when making the request. It's probably a bad idea because I am sure lots can go wrong

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you not want to hack the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a [simple script in Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp).